# Passing Context to Class results in getSystemService Returning Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android

This is driving me crazy... I've searched for the past 2 hours trying to solve this and I cannot figure out what's going on.

I'm relatively new to Android development, so maybe I'm missing something that a more experienced person can help me with.

I'm just trying to create a Notifier class that I can call to send a notification to the user.

```
public class Notifier {

private Context mContext;

public Notifier(Context mContext){
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("foo")
        .setContentText("bar")
        .setOngoing(true);

NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
      (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


public void showNotification(){
    mNotifyMgr.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Main:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Notifier notifier = new Notifier(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Error:

```
01-25 13:11:25.211 27537-27537/net.alexdespain.mediamute E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: net.alexdespain.mediamute, PID: 27537
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.alexdespain.mediamute/net.alexdespain.mediamute.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at net.alexdespain.mediamute.Notifier.<init>(Notifier.java:27)
                                                                               at net.alexdespain.mediamute.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

It appears that the error is caused by:

```
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
      (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

But I don't understand why mContext would be null...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
  (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

This is a field with an initializer. The initializer will be invoked before the constructor. `mContext` is `null` at this point. Initialize the field (and the `mBuilder` field) inside the constructor instead:

```
public Notifier(Context mContext){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mNotifyMgr =
      (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder =
(NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("foo")
    .setContentText("bar")
    .setOngoing(true);
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I figured it might be something like that...